# How to make `cols` to float?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, object, apply, nan

`cols=[Bird1, Bird2, Bird3]`

I would like to float the `cols` columns.
By applying the code below, the `cols` columns are floated, but the numerical values ​​of the columns turn to NaN.

| Bird1 | Bird2 | Bird3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22.1 | 33.1 | 33,7 |
| `[-11059] No Good Data For Calculation` | 4 | 33,3 |
| 3.3 | `[-11059] No Good Data For Calculation` | 99,7 |
| 1.0 | 55.5 | 22,1 |

`df2[cols] = df2[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)`

| Bird1 | Bird2 | Bird3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |

How to make `cols` to float so that numeric values ​​remain?

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your dataframe's structure with `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`?

Comment: you should provide the input as a dataframe constructor for reproducibility